# Is it common to vocalize syllabic L, but use dark L as a coda consonant after unreduced vowels?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, phonetics

This question is about words that **end** in a syllabic L like

> little /ˈlɪtl/ capital /ˈkæpɪtl/ able /ˈeɪbl/ bible /ˈbaɪbl/ syllable
>   /ˈsɪləbl/

**Question 1:** 
Is it common for people who usually pronounce L as a dark L in the syllable coda to make an exception when the word ends in a syllabic L, and to then vocalize the L instead?

From observing my own speech I notice that when I say "ball" or "call" the L is a dark L. 
But, when the L is also a syllabic L, e.g. *little* or *capital,* 
the tip of my tongue does **not** touch the roof of my mouth behind my teeth – so I assume it is vocalized. (I am a native English speaker)

An extract from rachelsenglish.com:

> http://rachelsenglish.com/syllabic-consonants/
>
> To make the Dark L, pull the back of the tongue back. Uhl, uhl. Leave
>   the tongue tip forward and down, the middle down too. Uhl, -uhl. So
>   that’s the sound we want when we see schwa-L.

**Question 2:** 
Rachel says "leave the tongue tip forward and down" 
i.e. the tongue tip does not touch the roof of the mouth. Does this mean she is saying "vocalize L"?

**Question 3:** 
 Is an L where the tip of the tongue does not touch the roof of the mouth a vocalized L?

Comment: Are you talking palatized like Valley Girl "cool"? Or the same sound after glottalized tt, as in various London accents?

Comment: I would consider those to be syllabic /l/s so it's no surprise they behave differently.

Comment: Words like "able", "little", "brittle" I vocalize the L. But If I say "Ball" or "Call" the L is a dark L. so I wonder if this is common or just my own idiolect.

Comment: It’s not /tl/ or /le/. /tl/ isn’t a valid way for a word to end in English, and /le/, more commonly be written /leɪ/, is as in ‘chipotle’ or ‘mêlée’. What all your examples end in is /əl/: an /l/ preceded by a schwa. The schwa gets ‘eaten’ by the /l/, which becomes syllabic [l̩] (some would there is no schwa phoneme there at all, and /l̩/ is just the phoneme). I would personally be equally likely to vocalise a syllabic and a non-syllabic /l/, but I wouldn’t find it surprising for someone to only vocalise one or the other.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I don't think everyone agrees that syllabic L is phonemically /əl/. I think there is nothing wrong with the transcription /tl/. Word final /təl/ and /tl/ do not contrast in standard English, outside of maybe some weird exceptional cases

Comment: thanks, I made changes to my question. please advise if it sounds better.

Comment: @sumelic You’re right of course that if you don’t accept a schwa there, there’s no reason to posit a phonemically syllabic /l̩/. I shouldn’t be commenting in the middle of the night while troubleshooting Windows issues. (Though I did say that some would say there’s no schwa phoneme at all, at least.)

Comment: Hi James. Are you an American English speaker?

Comment: What is 'vocalized' (I don't recognize that as a technical term)? Is that like 'voiced'? (all these different 'l's are voiced). Also all these word final 'l's are 'dark' for me, so I think it is a no answer from me for question 1. (I am AmE speaker)

Comment: By coincidence [a question on this on Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27052/dark-l-vs-l-vocalisation). And 'vocalized' is just the term for the counterpart to 'dark', for 'l'.

Comment: @Mitch Hi Mitch. That answer misunderstands the question because of a homophony relating to *vocalised* ('being in the nucleus of a syllable' versus 'being turned into a vowel/occurring as a articulatorily phonetic vowel when one might otherwise expect a consonant'). But even so *vocalised*, in the sense that neither OP meant but the respondent did, is not  the 'counterpart' to *dark* in any way. For example, there are dialects of English which have clear syllabic L.

Comment: @Mitch So, [l], like other approximants is phonetically very like a vowel, there is no friction and not enough of any kind of obstruction to the airflow to cause any stoppge of the air leaving the mouth or to cause any audible friction. Consequently there is no increase in the air pressure within the mouth, and the wave form measured will be periodic, very much like that of a vowel. And as a result of this we still can detect vowel-like qualities in the sound even when the tongue makes contact with the alveolar ridge. If the quality is relatively neutral, perhaps like a schwa [ə] ...

Comment: @Mitch ... , we say that the /l/ is clear. When it has a quality of a back rounded vowel, like the vowel in the word *pull*, we say that it is dark. That is not the same thing as being a syllabic L, even if for many speakers syllabic L is usually dark.

Answer (score 5):

**Question 1**

Here is the relevant excerpt from *Gimson's Pronunciation of English* (Eighth edition. p. 219) in terms of what happens in General British:[image]

So, in British English, at least, it's common for people who  normally use dark [ɫ] in syllable codas to use a vocalised /l/, [ʊ], for word final syllabic /l/. However, this is more common when the preceding consonant involves the lips in some way (is bilabial or labio-dental). So more speakers will use a vocalic allophone in words such as *able, bible*  and *syllable* than will for *little* or *capital*. The distribution in General American will probably be slightly different.

**Question 2**

In relation to the Rachel's English video, it would indeed be the case that if she wasn't using the tip of her tongue to make an alveolar contact, she would be producing a vocalised /l/. *However*, this is not what she is doing! She is making a regular dark [ɫ].

We cannot tell for certain why Rachel is giving that description of dark [ɫ], but I would bet a lot of money that  the reason is that when doing her research, she was confused by the very misleading linguistic terminology.

Unfortunately, in linguistics the named parts of the tongue do not correspond to intuition or common sense. When you look in the mirror your tongue looks kind of flat and thin. This is an illusion. Your tongue is really a big fat ball with a bit stuck on the front of it.

When we talk about the tongue, there is the front bit which we use for most consonants. We can flap it about in all kinds of different ways. That's the BLADE of your tongue, the very end of which is the TIP. The part of the tongue that we are interested in right now is the big ball of muscle behind that. It starts where the tongue joins the floor of your mouth.

[image]

In the stylised diagram above, the blade of your tongue is represented by the small pink rectangular section. The square behind that represents the ball of your tongue. Now when we talk about the FRONT of your tongue raising or lowering, we are talking about the front of this back part of your tongue—the part represented by the square above. So when you think of your tongue in normal everyday terms, this is actually about half way down your tongue as you look at it in the mirror.

Now when we make a dark [ɫ], the tip and blade of the tongue make contact with the alveolar ridge and the ***front*** of the tongue remains low, while the back is raised. So the surface of the tongue assumes a concave shape as it dips downwards and then rises back up again at the back. It sounds very much as though Rachel has read in the literature that the *front* of the tongue is low for dark [ɫ] and has interpreted this to mean that the *tip* of the tongue is low (which, of course, is completely incorrect).

**Question 3**

Yes, an allophone of /l/ which doesn't involve the tongue touching the top of the mouth is probably a vocalised /l/.

---

**Notes from Gimson on other varieties of English**

Here is some further information from Gimson regarding dialects other than GB:

[image]

Comment: Is it just me, or does the end of the first Gibson quote not make any sense? After alveolar plosives the /l/ is regularly released laterally, but pronunciations like /ˡlɪtəl, mɪdəl/ (i.e., with lateral release) are increasingly heard? So normally lateral, but increasingly lateral. Say wha? (I actually find this surprising—it had never occurred to me that vocalised /l/ might be more more common after labials in RGB. I find I have to strain to vocalise _people_ and velarise _uncle_: my instinct is to vocalise either both or neither.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What he means by 'lateral release', is that the air  being compressed behind the closure for the plosive isn't cleanly released into the air flowing out of the mouth. Instead, because the following [l] is homorganic, the tip of the tongue, stays on the alveolar ridge and the air is released by the side rims of the tongue suddenly lowering  allowing the air to escape laterally (sideways). With /ˡlɪtəl/ or /mɪdəl/  the air from the plosive is released cleanly ('centrally', not laterally) during the transition from plosive to vowel (schwa). The releases sound a bit  different.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Of course, Cruttenden is talking phonetics, not phonology here. Interesting about your pron. I've discovered that I do vocalise in *people* even though I thought I didn't. I don't *think* I vocalise with *uncle* in normal speech - but who knows ...?

Comment: Oh, release of the **plosive**. That makes sense.

Comment: I'm confused. In the first Gimson quote - Is "L" in "little" and "middle" usually vocalised? Or is vocalising it "childish" and avoided?

Comment: @James Some RP speakers vocalise it, but less so than with other words. Some RP speakers will find such articulations a bit child-like.